# Express JS middleware function - jwt.verify() is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, middleware

I have a middleware to authenticate user via access & refresh token (JWT).

Everything was working fine until I put **typescript** into my project.

Here's my code:

```
import { UserJWTPayload } from '../interfaces/UserJWTPayload'
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'
import { ResponseObject } from '../api/classes/ResponseObject'
import SequelizeApi from '../sequelize/sequelize-api'
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const authenticateUserTokens = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const accessToken: string = req.cookies.access_token
        const refreshToken: string = req.cookies.refresh_token

        if (!accessToken || !refreshToken) return res.status(401).json(new ResponseObject(false, 'not authenticated', null))

        console.log(jwt)
        /*
        [Module: null prototype] {
            decode: [Function (anonymous)],
            default: {
                decode: [Function (anonymous)],
                verify: [Function (anonymous)],
                sign: [Function (anonymous)],
                JsonWebTokenError: [Function: JsonWebTokenError],
                NotBeforeError: [Function: NotBeforeError],
                TokenExpiredError: [Function: TokenExpiredError]
            }
        }
        */

        console.log(jwt.verify())
        /*
            export function verify(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: Secret, options?: VerifyOptions & { complete?: false }): JwtPayload | string;
            An argument for 'token' was not provided 
        */

        console.log(jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY))
        /*
        TypeError: jwt.verify is not a function
            at file:///C:/Users/Jakub/Desktop/Projekty/StoriesBatchApi/src/middlewares/authenticate-user-tokens.ts:16:25
            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
            at file:///C:/Users/Jakub/Desktop/Projekty/StoriesBatchApi/src/middlewares/authenticate-user-tokens.ts:7:71
            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
            at __awaiter (file:///C:/Users/Jakub/Desktop/Projekty/StoriesBatchApi/src/middlewares/authenticate-user-tokens.ts:3:12)
            at file:///C:/Users/Jakub/Desktop/Projekty/StoriesBatchApi/src/middlewares/authenticate-user-tokens.ts:7:96
            at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\Projekty\StoriesBatchApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
            at next (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\Projekty\StoriesBatchApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
            at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\Projekty\StoriesBatchApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
            at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\Projekty\StoriesBatchApi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) 
        */

        const accessTokenData = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY) as UserJWTPayload

        const refreshTokenFromDatabase = await SequelizeApi.getModel('user_token').findOne({ where: { refresh_token: refreshToken } })

        if (!refreshTokenFromDatabase) return res.status(401).json(new ResponseObject(false, 'invalid refresh token', null))

        jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_PRIVATE_KEY)

        res.locals.id_user = accessTokenData.id_user

        return next()
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        return res.status(401).json(new ResponseObject(false, 'server error | not authenticated', e.message))
    }

};

export default authenticateUserTokens
```

I console logged JWT object as well, but it didn't help to understand what's going on.

I will provide protected route too:

```
userRouter.delete('/:id', authenticateUserTokens(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const deletedUserId = parseInt(req.params.id)
        const actionByUserId = parseInt(res.locals.id_user)

        if (actionByUserId !== deletedUserId) 
            return res.status(403).json(new ResponseObject(false, 'not authorized', null))

        const arrayOfAffectedRows = await userModel.update({ status: 'deleted' }, {
            where: {
                id: deletedUserId
            }
        })

        if (arrayOfAffectedRows[0] === 1) 
            return res.status(200).json(new ResponseObject(true, 'user deleted', null)) 
        else 
            return res.status(404).json(new ResponseObject(false, 'user not found', null))
    } catch(e) {
        return res.status(500).json(new ResponseObject(false, 'server error', e))
    }
})
```

Here's my tsconfig.ts file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES6",
        "removeComments": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution":"node",
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
    "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

I use nodemon to run app in development:

`nodemon -r dotenv/config --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --esm src/server.ts`

I tried removing brackets in protected route:

`authenticateUserTokens()` ---> `authenticateUserTokens`

But it throwed error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by correcting import:

`import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'` --> `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'` instead.

Why?

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
```

Means that you are asking for an object with all of the named exports of `jsonwebtoken`.

Then you can access any of the exports in `jsonwebtoken` as something.name. In this case they will be something. but in the `jsonwebtoken` this the file they are exporting:

`node-jsonwebtoken/index.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  verify: require('./verify'),
  sign: require('./sign'),
  JsonWebTokenError: require('./lib/JsonWebTokenError'),
  NotBeforeError: require('./lib/NotBeforeError'),
  TokenExpiredError: require('./lib/TokenExpiredError'),
};

Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'decode', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: require('./decode'),
});
```